# Assignment not working inside LogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, functions

Why doesn't the assignment with `T` work within the plot function? It seems like `T` is being evaluated as a constant. When I place the assignment `T = 10000/(1 + x/100)` outside the plot function, it works.

```
LogLinearPlot[{20 Log[10, T = 10000/(1 + x/100)], 
  20 Log[10, T/(1 + T)]}, {x, 1, 10^10}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

This is the expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Attributes[LogLinearPlot]

(* {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

Whenever you have problems with a plot, check on whether [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) helps (because of the [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute).

```
LogLinearPlot[
 Evaluate@{20 Log[10, T = 10000/(1 + x/100)], 20 Log[10, T/(1 + T)]},
 {x, 1, 10^10},
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could define `T` within `With`:

```
With[{T = 10000/(1 + x/100)},
 LogLinearPlot[{
   20 Log[10, T],
   20 Log[10, T/(1 + T)]}, {x, 1, 10^10},
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> {"20 Log[10,T]", "20 Log[10,T/(1+T)]"},
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]]
```

[image]